# Beamer overlay specification and tcblistings

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, overlays, tcblisting

I have a beamer slide with several code snippets formatted using tcblisting and displayed using tcb raster blocks. I would like to reveal the tcblisting blocks one at a time, but I haven't been able to get the overlay specification right.

Here's the Beamer `frame`:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
  \begin{ccodeblock}{C Source}
    long plus(long x, long y);

    void sumstore(long x, long y, long *dest)
    {
      long t = plus(x, y);
      *dest = t;
    }
  \end{ccodeblock}
  \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height]
    \begin{gascodeblock}{Assembly Output (x86-64)}
      sumstore:
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    %rdx, %rbx
        call    plus
        movq    %rax, (%rbx)
        popq    %rbx
        ret
    \end{gascodeblock}
    \begin{verbatimcodeblock}{Machine Code}
      0x53 0x48 0x89 0xd3 0xe8
      0xf2 0xff 0xff 0xff 0x48
      0x89 0x03 0x5b 0xc3
    \end{verbatimcodeblock}
  \end{tcbraster}
\end{frame}
```

The `ccodeblock`, `gascodeblock`, and `verbatimcodeblock` are defined using `\newtcblisting`. I would like to have:

- `ccodeblock` on all slides
- `gascodeblock` on `<2->`
- `verbatimcodeblock` on `<3->`

I have tried using `\only`, `\onlyenv`, etc., but end up with the overlay specifications (e.g., `<2->`) showing up in the typeset output.

thanks,
tom.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: tcolorbox provides an only key for use with beamer

Answer (score 1):

*I don't want to guess how your custom `tcblisting`s are defined, so I just took some random code from the `tcolorbox` manual.*

Simply using `\pause` works fine if the frame option `fragile=singleslide` is replaced by `fragile` -- which makes sense, as you want to have fragile content on multiples slides.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{tcblisting}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}
    long plus(long x, long y);

    void sumstore(long x, long y, long *dest)
    {
      long t = plus(x, y);
      *dest = t;
    }
  \end{tcblisting}
  \pause
  \begin{tcblisting}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}
    sumstore:
      pushq   %rbx
      movq    %rdx, %rbx
      call    plus
      movq    %rax, (%rbx)
      popq    %rbx
      ret
  \end{tcblisting}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]